# Python: how to substitute and know whether it matched

Tags: python, regex

I know that `re.sub(pattern, repl,text)` can substitute when pattern matches, and then return the substitute.

My code is:

```
text = re.sub(pattern, repl, text1)
```

I have to define another variable to check whether it is modified:

```
text2 = re.sub(pattern, repl, text1)
matches = text2 != text1
text1 = text2
```

It has issues, for example with: `text1='abc123def'` , `pattern = '(123|456)'`, `repl = '123'`.
After replacement, it is the same string, so `matches` is false, but it actually matches.

Comment: why are you substituting `123` for `123`?

Comment: e.g. I need know wheather it contains numbers. patterns=r'\d+'

Comment: replace all numbers to 123, is it possible?

Comment: There is `re.subn` which returns a tuple `(new_string, number)`, where `new_string` is the replacement text, while `number` is the number of substitutions made.  Check out the `re` module docs.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use [`re.subn`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.subn)

> Perform the same operation as sub(), but return a tuple (new_string, number_of_subs_made).

and then check the number of replacements that were made. For example:

```
text2, numReplacements = re.subn(pattern, repl, text1)
if numReplacements:
    # did match
else:
    # did not match
```

Answer (score 1):

The `repl` parameter can also be a function which takes an RE match object and returns what the replacement should be; this function is not called if the text doesn't match. You could use that to do what you needed then just return a constant string you want to replace it with. This would cut down on an unneeded second check against the RE.

Comment: This is true, however the `re.subn` provides the desired functionality with less clutter than a callable `repl` parameter.

Comment: Your post should include an example using the command you suggest. Left as is, it&#39;s actually a comment, not a full answer. Comments are great for providing hints, or useful information without going through the trouble of writing a complete answer. Please `edit` to turn your suggestion into a solution. As per SO guidelines, most posts should include code. And answers should provide actual solutions, where possible.

Answer (score 0):

"Whether string contains numbers":

```
for text1 in ('abc123def', 'adsafasdfafdsafqw', 'fsadfoi81we'):
    print("Text %s %s numbers." %
          ((text1, )  + (
              ('does not contain',) if not any(c.isdigit() for c in text1)
               else ('contains',))
           ))
```